# Spring boot & MyBatis xml query for update list

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, spring-boot, mybatis

I try to update a column my Mybatis xml Mapper.
The parameterType is Request class, and it contained List type object.
I want to get that object from class to xml mapper.
But I got an issue like this continueously. What's the problem?

Here is my xml code

```
<update id="moveEBookShelf" parameterType = "kyobobook.digital.application.domain.bsh.EBookShelfMoveBshRequest">
    <foreach item="bsh" index="index" collection="resultList" open="(" separator="," close=")">
        UPDATE EOU.T_UI_DGCT_BSH_M
           SET DGCT_BSH_ARNG_SRMB = #{bsh.bshArrgNum}
           WHERE DGCT_BSH_NUM = #{bsh.bshNum}
    </foreach>      
</update>
```

Request class looks like this,

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class EBookShelfMoveBshRequest extends DataTableRequest {

    private String updown;
    List<EBookShelf> resultList;

}
```

And EBookShelf code like this

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
public class EBookShelf{

    private int bshNum;         
    private String bshName;     
    private int bshArrgNum;     
    private String dltYN;       

    private int totalCount;   

}
```

Finally I got and issue like this

EOU.T_UI_DGCT_BSH_M SET DGCT_BSH_ARNG_SRMB = 3 WHERE DGCT_BSH_NUM = 278008 , UPDATE EOU.T_UI_DGCT_BSH_M
SET DGCT_BSH_ARNG_SRMB = 2 WHERE DGCT_BSH_NUM = 278009 , UPDATE EOU.T_UI_DGCT_BSH_M SET DGCT_BSH_ARNG_SRMB
= 4 WHERE DGCT_BSH_NUM = 278010 )  {FAILED after 11 ms}
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPDATE"
Position: 11
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)

Answer (score 0):

```
<update id="moveEBookShelf" parameterType = "kyobobook.digital.application.domain.bsh.EBookShelfMoveBshRequest">
    <foreach item="bsh" index="index" collection="resultList" open=" " separator=";" close=" ">
        UPDATE EOU.T_UI_DGCT_BSH_M
           SET DGCT_BSH_ARNG_SRMB = #{bsh.bshArrgNum}
           WHERE DGCT_BSH_NUM = #{bsh.bshNum}
    </foreach>      
</update>
```

Comment: While the code might help OP. For it to be a complete answer please consider adding an explaination as to why this solves the question placed by OP.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It worked!!!
Can I ask you one more question? 
What is the difference between 
open=" " separator=";" close=" "
and 
open="(" separator="," close=")"
???

Comment: open="(" separator="," close=")  get result sql 
(update table set .. where .. , update table set .. where )

open=" " separator=";" close=" "  get result sql 
update table set .. where .. ;
update table set .. where ..